# web3.eth.subscribe with logs does not return transactions for some wallets

Tags: web3js, logs

I have given `logs = []` as a setting and this works for the tether wallet: `0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7` but does not work for the bybit exchange wallet: `0xf89d7b9c864f589bbf53a82105107622b35eaa40`

Is this because the transactions on the bybit wallet are all Ether transfers, which do not emit a log/topic, as opposed to erc20 transfer of USDT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bybit address is an external owned account. As such it won't emit log entries. Only contracts can emit log entries.

It should be possible to track ERC20 transfers from any address. You should track the `Transfer` event and either `to` or `from` parameters with the desired address.